# Spring Boot - Request Mapping won't accept trailing slash or multiple directories

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, request-mapping

When RequestMapping in my controller, I'm able to map an html file to "/" and another to "/users". However, trying to map to "/users/" or "/users/test" won't work. In the console it'll say that the endpoint was mapped, but on trying to access it I'll get the 404 error page.

```
package com.bridge.Bitter.controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class BitterController {

    //works
    @RequestMapping(value="/")
    public String getMainPage(){
        return "main.html";
    }

    //works
    @RequestMapping(value="/users")
    public String getUsersPage(){
        return "users.html";
    }

    //doesn't work, Whitelabel error page
    @RequestMapping(value="/users/")
    public String getUsersSlashPage(){
        return "users.html";
    }
    //doesn't work, Whitelabel error page
    @RequestMapping(value="/users/test")
    public String getUsersTestPage(){
        return "users.html";
    }

}
```

My application.properties only contains "spring.data.rest.basePath=/api".

If I change from @Controller to @Rest Controller, The following occurs:

```
package com.bridge.Bitter.controllers;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@RestController
public class BitterController {

    //works
    @RequestMapping(value="/")
    public String getMainPage(){
        return "main.html";
    }

    //returns a webpage with the text "users.html" on it instead of serving the html
    @RequestMapping(value="/users")
    public String getUsersPage(){
        return "users.html";
    }

    //returns a webpage with the text "users.html" on it instead of serving the html
    @RequestMapping(value="/users/")
    public String getUsersSlashPage(){
        return "users.html";
    }
    //returns a webpage with the text "users.html" on it instead of serving the html
    @RequestMapping(value="/users/test")
    public String getUsersTestPage(){
        return "users.html";
    }

}
```

Changing the functions from returning strings to returning

```
new ModelAndView("user.html")
```

works for /users but will then 404 error for /users/ and /users/test.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to map the same path twice. /users is treated the same as /users/, so Spring can not resolve which controller method should handle the request.

You can just try this:

```
package com.bridge.Bitter.controllers;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class BitterController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String getMainPage(){
        return "main.html";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/users")
    public String getUsersPage(){
        return "users.html";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/users/test")
    public String getUsersTestPage(){
        return "users.html";
    }
}
```

In the other hand, when you use [@RestController annotation](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.2.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RestController.html), you always return a response text in JSON format, that's why you always get the same result.

Comment: Even if I'm only mapping one, as in my controller only contains the mapping for /users/, it won't map to localhost:8080/users/. Same for if I JUST have /users/test.
However, /users works.

Method names shouldn't have been the same, that was a mistake on my part in the question.